# EF .net core re-encapsulation error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I encapsulate the DbContext class in my DbContextBase class.
And something about delegating problem.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling;
    public abstract class DbContextBase : DbContext
    {
            public Task<int> ExecuteSaveChangesAsync()
            {
                  return this.ExecuteAsync(base.SaveChangesAsync);
            }
            private Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskFunc)
            {
                return this.retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(taskFunc);
            }
    }
```

the **SaveChangesAsync** function is the virtual method at the DbContext  clsss (EF Core)

```
   public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
```

I got the error :

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'DbContextBase.ExecuteAsync(Func>)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I have no idea about it. Anyone help?

usage:

```
public Task<int> SaveOrUpdateAsync<T>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> identifierExpression) where T : class
    {
        EntityEntry<T> entry = this.Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            this.Set<T>().Add(entity);

        if (this.Set<T>().Any(identifierExpression))
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        return this.ExecuteSaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] showing how you call this method.

Comment: this `this.ExecuteAsync(base.SaveChangesAsync);` should be `this.ExecuteAsync<int>(base.SaveChangesAsync);` Because `TResult` (`int` here) can't be determined by the compiler.

Comment: @CodeNotFound
 I got error "
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<Task<int>>'"

Comment: SO I think you should do this => `this.ExecuteAsync<int>(() => base.SaveChangesAsync());`

Comment: @CodeNotFound 
Thank you !I It's work. :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound what's difference between "() => base.SaveChangesAsync()" and "base.SaveChangesAsync" ?